# error installing distribute_setup.py from virtual environment on linux

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, distribute

I have been trying for a few hours to get distribute_setup.py to install correctly in an active virtual environment.  I get it to run, but I always get an error.  Any help would be appreciated.  I am currently trying to do this in Ubuntu 12.10.

Thanks!

```
 python distribute_setup.py
 Extracting in /tmp/tmpvmrkpz
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "distribute_setup.py", line 546, in <module>
 sys.exit(main())
 File "distribute_setup.py", line 543, in main
 return _install(tarball, _build_install_args(options))
 File "distribute_setup.py", line 76, in _install
 tar = tarfile.open(tarball)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/tarfile.py", line 1571, in open
 raise ReadError("file could not be opened successfully")
 tarfile.ReadError: file could not be opened successfully
 (DjangoTutorial) test@ubuntu:~$
```

(DjangoTutorial) is the active virtual environment

Here is what I get when I try to build the dependencies

```
test@ubuntu:~/Code/Tutorial$ sudo apt-get build-dep python3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list
test@ubuntu:~/Code/Tutorial$
```

Python3.3 is installed in /usr/local/lib

I also tried reinstalling ubuntu and python3.3 and it still doesnt work!

Comment: What Linux distro are you using? Most provide pre-made packages.

Comment: I am using ubuntu 12.10

Comment: Do you have enough disk space to download the tar file? Or to extract it to tmp?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesnt seem like a virtual environment problem. Rather a problem of missing dependencies for your python installation. Try

```
sudo apt-get build-dep python3
```

Then try to configure and build python3.3 again. Also add the -dev package

```
sudo apt-get install python3.3-dev
```

Now try installing your package. Most likely you want to create your virtual environment again.

tarfile.py tries to open the tarball using one of the four extraction methods (tar, gzip, bz2, xopen) and it errors out if it cant find respective modules in the python library, some of which might not be included in the base python package.

Comment: Unfortunetly this did not work.  I can't get build-dep python3 to run succesfully. Any ideas?

Comment: can you share the error as an edit in your question. Also, please indicate where your python3.3 installation is so that its easier to remove it before your reconfigure it.

Comment: Just added more detail.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: if you dont mind installing ubuntu again then this (http://askubuntu.com/questions/244544/how-to-install-python-3-3) is a good resource to help you install python3.3  which also includes instructions to setup venv. Since you want to work with virtual environments, so it shouldnt matter if your python installation is in /opt/. Remember to build dependencies before you install python3.3. For that you can edit the file `/etc/apt/sources.list` and add the source (`deb-src` line) corresponding to your location as given by https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors

Comment: Ok, I got it to install the build dependencies but it is now saying I need zlib to run setup.py of distribute.py

Comment: That has been the problem ever since. As I mentioned in the answer, tarfile.py tries to import gzip modules and zlib is one of them. Installing dependencies and then compiling python again solves this problem since the zlib module (which is a C module) is fetched in the building dependency phase. I am quite sure that if you remove your python installation first (`sudo apt-get purge python3.3`) and build dependencies and then install python again, this would solve the problem. As a quick and dirty fix (which I wont suggest) you can do `apt-get install zlib1g-dev` to solve your problem for now.

Answer (score 2):

`distribute_setup.py` will attempt to download the package (from the net) and then install it. Perhaps your download cannot complete for some reason and that is why the next step (Extracting the tarball) fails.

You can try to download the source from [here](https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/distribute-0.6.36.tar.gz#md5=a923385de72dcdca68cd4ac2b9dc1148) and then install it manually.

1. Extract the downloaded tar

   `$ tar -xzvf distribute-0.6.36.tar.gz`
2. Change to the extracted directory

   `$ cd distribute-0.6.36`
3. Run install

   `$ python setup.py install`